# Purchase from random account showing up in Mac App Store?

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, apple-id

There's an app in my Mac App Store update list called "Mahjong Deluxe Free". I have never downloaded this app, let alone play mahjong (is that normal?).

Upon trying to clear it from the list by updating it, I am presented with the following:

[image]

The Apple ID entered is not mine, and I have never heard of it. No one else in my house uses my laptop, and I don't know anybody that still uses Hotmail.

I figured I would try clearing it by finding the app and downloading it with my own Apple ID, but the following:

[image]

I click `OK`, and it presents me with a final error, saying:

> We could not complete your request.
>
> There was an error in the App Store. Please try again later. (4)

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Usually this is due to someone emailing you that app or placing it on a connected share or drive. If you eject all drives, log out, physically unplug any drives and log back in, is the App still listed as needing an update? At that point, you'll need to search for it using spotlight to make sure it's not lying elsewhere on your storage drive.

Comment: The only drive I am connected to is my Time Capsule, but I do not believe that it would be able to find files within the encrypted DMG files on the drive. I might be wrong on that though. Other than that, I am not connected to any other drives.

Comment: The app store uses a simple spotlight search so that if you zipped a copy of an app, it should not show up as needing an update until such time as you uncompressed it and re-ran the update. Hopefully you can sort things out by using Spotlight or perhaps re-building the spotlight index.

Comment: Using Spotlight yields no results, but I will attempt to rebuild the index...

Comment: @bmike Alright, rebuilding the index does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by a Mac AppStore Receipt residing somewhere on your system that was issued for different account. Spotlight is generally of no use in finding these, since it can't go deep enough to find them within the places they are. Usually the offending receipt can be located with a simple command, that may have to be adjusted according to your file system structure.

Open Terminal and try:

```
cd /
```

then

```
find . -type f -name "receipt" -exec grep -s -R -n -i "com.ensenasoft" {} \;
```

- Press <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd> to cancel/stop

if located you will should see something such as:

```
Binary file Applications/Mahjong Deluxe Free.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt matches
```

If it failed to locate anything you will need to adjust the path, for example to search a different volume:

```
cd /Volumes/<Name of Volume>
```

then try the command again.

Comment: So far it has listed the following: `Binary file ./Applications/PackageMaker.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt matches`

Comment: That would likely be the one that would be causing it.  You can delete the entire PackageMaker.app or just delete the receipt `rm ./Applications/PackageMaker.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt` which should resolve the issue with the Mac AppStore.

Comment: Look at that, it worked! Thanks. I wonder why the receipt for an Apple app was the same as Mahjong...

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, and the solution was to delete the receipt, thanks!

Comment: I've been trying to fix this problem for what seems like a year! Maybe I'm OCD, but having that stupid 1 badge on the MAS was driving me nuts! A thousand thanks!

Comment: Thank you very very much, it was buging me and now it's working.
Same probleme, same solution.